# Questions about JSONP

Tags: jquery, json, callback, jsonp

Can someone point me in the right direction?

**Sample URL**:
        url.com/api/$order/config?fname=$fname&lname=$lname&serial_number=$sn

Code:

```
    var fullUrl = "[URLHERE.com]/api/$order/config?";
    $.ajax({
        url: fullUrl,
        contentType: "application/json",    
        dataType: "jsonp",
        type: 'GET',
        jsonp: '$callback',
        beforeSend: function setHeader(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', token);
        },
        success: callback,
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError);
        },
    });
```

Questions:

What does the "jsonp: '$callback'," line do?

How can I retrieve fname, lname, and serial_number?

Does the jsonp callback outputs a json data file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From jquery docs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> jsonp
>
> Type: String

Override the callback function name in a jsonp request. This value will be used instead of `callback` in the `callback=?` part of the query string in the url. So `{jsonp:'onJSONPLoad'}` would result in `onJSONPLoad=?` passed to the server. As of jQuery 1.5, setting the jsonp option to false prevents jQuery from adding the `?callback` string to the URL or attempting to use `=?` for transformation. In this case, you should also explicitly set the `jsonpCallback` setting. For example, `{ jsonp: false, jsonpCallback: "callbackName" }`

so the  `jsonp: '$callback',` line is setting the callback query param to a php var $callback

the success function is callback.  Look for that in your code and retrieve the values there

And, yes the results in the success function will be JSON

Comment: Thanks @barbara.  Do you know how I could modify the json once I call it back?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question about modifing the json.  You can read the json in the success function and modify it as needed, but that doesn't send it back to the server, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks, what I am trying to do is append data to the json and save a copy.